# Bash scripting: Get value before a count of linex between 2 words

Tags: bash, sed

The problem is as follows.

File:

```
Name1
  command
  data1
  data2
  data3
  done
Name2
  command
  data4
  data5
  done
Name1
  command
  data6
  done
```

In the file above, I want to count the lines between "command" and "done" and give a list of names where this count is more then 1.

the output here should be:

```
Name1
Name2
```

I've experimented with:

> sed -n "/command/,/done/p" | count

Any idea's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a way:

```
$ awk '/done/ {if (t>1) print name} {t++} /^Name/ {name=$0} /command/ {t=0}' a
Name1
Name2
```

#### Explanation

- `/done/ {if (t>1) print name}` if the line contains `done`, print the title of the block just if the counter is > 1.
- `{t++}` increment the counter in any case.
- `/^Name/ {name=$0}` store the line value.
- `/command/ {t=0}` if the line contains `command`, reset the counter.

Comment: Yes, this is the given pattern.

Comment: if "command" is not a literal string, then do that logic in the "Name" action block: `/^[^[:space:]]/ {name=$0; t=0; getline"`

Answer (score 2):

How about this awk:

```
awk '/^[A-Z]/{name=$0;count=-1;next}/done/&&count>1{print name;next}{count++}' file
```

Output:

```
Name1
Name2
```

That says, if the line starts with a left-aligned capital letter, save that as the name of the command and set the counter to -1 ... so that it will be zero after the next line when "command" appears". Then move to next line without further ado. If the line matches the string "done" and the counter is greater than one, print the name we saved earlier and move to next line. Increment counter for all other lines.

Answer (score 1):

If `Name` are not fixed string then you can use:

```
awk '/command/{cmd=1; n=0;next} !cmd{p=$1;next} cmd{n++} /done/{if (n>2) print p; cmd=0; next}' dat
Name1
Name2
```